# siblings() doesnt work for links under ul li

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two submenus which I hightlight them when they are active with this jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#links').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
    });
})
 </script>
```

but now I have another submenu which I want to use the same code but it doesnt work because the siblings() function wont work in it because the links are under li tag! and here is the code I tried for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabs_rubriken  a').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
    });
})
 </script>
```

and when I click on them they get hightlighed but they wont remove the class 'selected' when other link is clicked in that menu. by the way this menu must be ordered with ul li.

THe markup:

```
<div id="tab2">
<ul class="tabs_rubriken">
    <li><a class="submenu_produkts_links2" href="#armreifen">Armreifen</a></li>
    <li><a class="submenu_produkts_links2" href="#colliers">Colliers Anhänger</a></li>
    <li><a class="submenu_produkts_links2" href="#ohrschmuck">Ohrschmuck</a></li>
    <li><a class="submenu_produkts_links2" href="#ringe">Ringe</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="armreifen">[tabs slidertype="images" auto="yes" autospeed="4000"]
[imagetab width="800" height="500"] image.png [/imagetab]
[imagetab width="800" height="500"] image.png [/imagetab]
[/tabs]</div>
<div id="colliers">Colliers Anhänger</div>
<div id="ohrschmuck">Ohrschmuck</div>
<div id="ringe">Ringe</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please post your markup?

Comment: Traverse. `$(this).addClass(...).parent().siblings().children('a').removeClass(...)` [jQuery API for Traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) You should study these docs.

Comment: @user1689607  I did this but its work, it selects the li's and it doest remove the classes again

Comment: @TooCooL: I had the `addClass` on the wrong element at first. Try the current example.

Comment: or: `$(this).addClass('selected').closest('li').find('a').removeClass('selected');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabs_rubriken a').click(function(){
        $('a.selected', this.parentElement.parentElement).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
})
```

Comment: This wored but I cant exept your answer before 7 minutes

Comment: @TooCooL: Be careful. This will remove the `selected` class from all `a` elements on the page, so if your other nav menu uses `a` elements, it will be affected by this code. Not sure if that's an issue for your code.

Comment: @TooCooL No worries. You might want to wait and see if there's other answers. Questions with accepted answers get less attention.

Comment: @user1689607 Fixed that edge case

Comment: @user1689607 Add `siblings` where?

Comment: @Asad: I think you know that you had `$(this).parent().find("a.selected")` before you edited it. Clearly this would require `.siblings()`. When you changed your answer, I deleted the comment.

Comment: @user1689607 No, I had `$(this).parent().find("a.selected")`, but alright

Comment: @Asad: Right, I was working from memory. Already updated my comment. Anyway, FWIW, `.parentNode` has broader support than `.parentElement`, which will fail below FF9.